# Could not find Drawdowns function - PerformanceAnalytics loaded

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am getting 'Could not find Drawdowns function' error . I have already loaded PerformanceAnalytics library.

code:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPL.DF<-data.frame(Date=index(AAPL), coredata(AAPL[,1]))
AAPL.DF[,2]<-ROC(AAPL.DF[,2])
colnames(AAPL.DF)<-c("Date","rtn")
dailyRtn <- as.numeric(substring(AAPL.DF[,"rtn"],1,nchar(as.character(AAPL.DF[,"rtn"]))-1))
dailyDD <- as.vector(Drawdowns(dailyRtn/100))
```

below is the o/p in console window

```
> getSymbols("AAPL")
[1] "AAPL"
Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 109721 != reported length 200
> AAPL.DF<-data.frame(Date=index(AAPL), coredata(AAPL[,1]))
> AAPL.DF[,2]<-ROC(AAPL.DF[,2])
> colnames(AAPL.DF)<-c("Date","rtn")
> dailyRtn <- as.numeric(substring(AAPL.DF[,"rtn"],1,nchar(as.character(AAPL.DF[,"rtn"]))-1))
> dailyDD <- as.vector(Drawdowns(dailyRtn/100))
Error in as.vector(Drawdowns(dailyRtn/100)) : 
  could not find function "Drawdowns"
```

I am not getting why I am getting error message of Drawdowns function could not be found when I have successfully installed and loaded PerformanceAnalytics library

Comment: The problem is reproducible and is not a simple typopgraphical error. It is caused by a change in the package "PerformanceAnalytics". This fixes it: ``dailyDD <- as.vector(PerformanceAnalytics:::Drawdowns(dailyRtn/100))``

Comment: The original code for the ``Drawdowns()`` function may be found here: https://github.com/R-Finance/PerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/R/Drawdowns.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a Drawdowns function.  Depending on what you're doing, you may be interested in using either findDrawdowns or chart.Drawdown.  Also you can simplify your code a bit for calculating returns as shown below:

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("AAPL")
#  calculate returns based on Adjusted Close prices
AAPL.DF <- Return.calculate(AAPL[,6])[-1,]
dailyDD <- findDrawdowns(AAPL.DF)
chart.Drawdown(AAPL.DF)
```

I've used Adjusted_Close prices, (AAPL column 6) rather than the Open prices (AAPL column 1) in your original code since Addjusted_Close prices have been corrected for the split of AAPL in 2014 while Open prices are not adjusted.